# Loop through a request array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I have an array `worker_id[]` for multi select list in my form like this:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="worker_id[]" size="8">
     @foreach($workers as $worker)
          <option value= ... </option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

And in my controller, I want to call a function `addRepairWorker` in a loop so it inserts values from the `worker_id` array.

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    $this->validate($request, [
            'worker_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    foreach ( arguments ){
            $this->repairsService->addRepairWorker($request, $vehicle);
    }
}
```

What arguments do I need to use in `foreach`? Or is there some other way?
I am using Laravel 5.

**EDIT:**

Here is `addRepairWorker` function:

```
public function addRepairWorker(Request $request , Vehicle $vehicle){

        $workers_needed = null;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle, $idcko) {

            $workers_needed = new Repair_worker();
            $workers_needed->repair_id = $idcko; //$idcko is DB query, not important here
            $workers_needed->worker_id = $request->worker_id;

            DB::insert('insert into repair_worker (repair_id, worker_id) values (?, ?)',
                    [$workers_needed->repair_id, $workers_needed->worker_id]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Witch framework do you use?

Comment: Flag that in the question

Comment: I just did :) thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: `foreach($request->input('worker_id') as $val)` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: So then I just pass `$val` as function argument instead of `$request`?

Comment: Thing so. If the function takes an worker_id as param, yes

Comment: Doesn't work. I get this error `Argument 1 passed to App\Models\Repairs\RepairsService::addRepairWorker() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given`

Comment: Oh ok, then it seems that you dont need the `foreach` and just give the `$request` as parameter, but dont now the internal behavior of `addRepairWorker`

Comment: It does need a loop for sure, because `worker_id` in my form is an array of all workers selected from that list. If I give it just the `$request`, I get error saying it doesn't accept an array. Internal behavior of that function is simple, it wants only one `worker_id` per `$request` for sql `insert`.

Comment: Then you have to create for each an new request object, i look if it is possible.

Comment: You have to use: https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_duplicate  but i can not code that for you. Im not so into laravel.

Comment: I cutted out necessary code in that function. It is just simple `select` from database.

Comment: @Ady96 comment DB::insert out and add $worker_needed->save(); at the end.

Comment: But that doesn't fix the array problem

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions what framework do you use (if any) ?

Comment: @MaxZoom private non (mostly focus an abstraction of pattern and code behavior when i code for fun), at job we use mostly `symfony` for front-end. But have a look on `phalcon` too,  it is a framework as php extention. https://phalconphp.com/en/   https://symfony.com/   here comparsion of both http://vschart.com/compare/phalconphp/vs/symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the function repairService does but I think you are trying to this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->worker_id); $i++)
{
  $this->repairsService->addRepairWorker($request->worker_id[$i], $vehicle);
}
```

This will pass the worker_id and the vehicle for each multiple selected option.

Edit:

Your validation is also incorrect. You don't validate request arrays like that.

```
public function rules()
    {

       $rules = array();
        if(null !== $this->request->get('worker_id')){
            foreach ($this->request->get('worker_id') as $key => $val) {
                $rules['worker_id.' . $key] = 'required|integer';
            }
        }


            return $rules;
        }
```

Edit 2:

```
public function addRepairWorker($worker_id , Vehicle $vehicle){

        $workers_needed = null;


            $workers_needed = new Repair_worker();
            $workers_needed->repair_id = $idcko; //$idcko is DB query, not important here
            $workers_needed->worker_id = $worker_id;

            $workers_needed->save();
```

Comment: I am gettin same error as I mentioned in comment above :/ See updated question for that function details.

Comment: @Ady96 then post your addRepairWorker function.

Comment: I just did. Hope it helps.

Comment: What about that `rules()` function? How do I use it in my case? Or if I just use body of that function without returning `$rules`, will it work?

Comment: @Ady96 The rules() function is an standard function in a request class, which you should be using instead of validating in the controller. Anyway, try changing the foreach to my for, and my changes in the addrepairworker function. It should actually save the worker and loop through all the selected worker_id.

Comment: I didn't use the `rules` cause I kind of don't understand it and it did not work when I tried to use it but your for loop worked with edited `addRepairWorker` function, except you forgot to rename `$request` but I did so its fine! thanks a lot man.

Comment: Btw, `$workers_needed->save()` doesn't work for me. I have to use that insert. If I use `->save()` I get this error: `Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "updated_at" of relation "repair_worker" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t into "repair_worker" ("repair_id", "worker_id", "updated_a...
^ (SQL: insert into "repair_worker" ("repair_id", "worker_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (171, 4, 2017-04-28 15:00:25, 2017-04-28 15:00:25) returning "id")` where `171, 4` are my `id` values..

Comment: @Ady96 it has been fixed

Comment: Do you know why am I getting this error? I have tried to use `save` before but I always got this error.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the function itself to insert any assigned worker_id into DB

So in the controller

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    // perform validation
    :

    // if all validations successful call function
    $this->repairsService->addRepairWorker($request, $vehicle);
}
```

Now the function will handle multiple worker_id values:

```
public function addRepairWorker(Request $request , Vehicle $vehicle){

    $worker_id_array = $request->input('worker_id');
    foreach ($worker_id_array as $worker_id) {

       DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $vehicle, $idcko) {

         $workers_needed = new Repair_worker();
         $workers_needed->repair_id = $idcko; //$idcko is DB query, not important here
         $workers_needed->worker_id = $worker_id;

         DB::insert('insert into repair_worker (repair_id, worker_id) values (?, ?)',
                [$workers_needed->repair_id, $workers_needed->worker_id]);
    });

   }
}
```

If you expect that function may be called also for as single value, just add a check if input is an array.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it.